# Tomcat 6 Showing error after including glassfish 3 severs jar file in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2, glassfish-3

On my local system i am using glassfish server 3.0. I have included all servers jar file of glassfish3  on my actual server  that is having Tomcat6.
That is showing now following Exceptions:

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/login.jsp(178,36) The s:form tag declares that it accepts  dynamic attributes but does not implement the required interface
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:775)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1507)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2338)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2388)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2394)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:489)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2338)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1737)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:178)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:306)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
```

How to resolve this problem.
While deploying war file i am having following jar file included in my war file(from glashfish server)

```
bean-validator.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
freemarker-2.3.15.jar
javax.annotation.jar
jaxr-api-osgi.jar
jaxpc-api-osgi.jar
jsf-api.jar
jsf-impl.jar
jstl-impl.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar
ongl-2.7.3.jar
struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar
struts2-jquery-plugin-1.8.3.jar
webservices-api-osgi.jar
weld-osgi-bundle.jar
xwork-core-2.1.6.jar
javax.ejb.jar
javax.enterprise.deploy.jar
javax.jms.jar
javax.mail.jar
javax.management.j2ee.jar
javax.persistence.jar
javac.resource.jar
javax.security.auth.message.jar
javax.security.jacc.jar
javax.servlet.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar
javax.transaction.jar
```

Comment: can you show your login.jsp file and what all jars you have in your class-path?

Comment: Hi @UmeshAwasthi i included my jar file list please tell me which jar files shoud i remove. I also want to know how to avoide jar files while creating war. Login.jsp haveing only login id and password field

Comment: Please make sure that you have same version of jars from same distribution, seems you are using different jars from different distributions

Comment: I configured my local server as tomcat now there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

Ideally our Enterprise Applications should be independent of any Server we use. Hence all the servers have a lib folder where you can put any specific JARs required in that environment.

I would recommend you to remove the glassfish JARS from your project and place them in your local glasshfish server's lib (if they are not already there). Alternatively you can place the JARs in a differen folder and add that folder to classpath.

As per the stacktrace posted by you there is a conflict in the JARs... Since you have tomcat and glassfish, both jars on your actual server, when it loads the application it is loading Tag classes from wrong JAR for the taglib it is picking. Hence it is recommended to have only one JAR.